# Visualforce Page Previous/Next is not working once a record is opened

Tags: visualforce

I am using VF page to display list of Accounts, then on same  list i want to get details using rerender  & apex:detail . Following is code .[image] Previous  & Next are working fine until i havent clicked & open account,Once i opened any account,Previous/Next are not working

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="All Accounts In My Org">
        <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
        <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}">Previous</apex:commandLink>
        <apex:commandLink action="{!next}">Next</apex:commandLink>
    </apex:panelGrid>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="acc">
            <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
                <apex:commandLink reRender="ren">
                    {!acc.Name}
                    <apex:param value="{!acc.Id}" name="accId"/>
                </apex:commandLink>    
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!acc.Industry}" />
            <apex:column value="{!acc.Type}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!acc.Phone}"/>                
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:outputPanel id="ren">
        <apex:detail subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.accId}" relatedList="false"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reRender attribute of the commandlink to rerender the pageblocktable.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
    <apex:form >      
        <apex:pageBlock title="All Accounts In My Org">
            <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
                <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}" reRender="pageblocktable">Previous</apex:commandLink>
                <apex:commandLink action="{!next}"  reRender="pageblocktable">Next</apex:commandLink>
            </apex:panelGrid>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="acc"  id="pageblocktable">
                <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
                    <apex:commandLink reRender="ren">
                        {!acc.Name}
                        <apex:param value="{!acc.Id}" name="accId"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>    
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Industry}" />
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Type}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Phone}"/>                
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:outputPanel id="ren">
            <apex:detail subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.accId}" relatedList="false"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```